# How to pop up touch keyboard in edge kiosk mode when the input is focused

Tags: javascript, keyboard, microsoft-edge, kiosk-mode

When a html input is focused by javascript, the touch keboard doesn't pop up, I need to manually select the input with my finger to be able to show the touch keyboard.

Can I popup it by code or keep it always on display?

PS
I have added the next register values to show the touch keyboard.

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke = 1 HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\DisableNewKeyboardExperience = 1 HKCU\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\TabletMode = 1

Comment: Try to add these register values and check if this work for you:  `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke = 1
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\DisableNewKeyboardExperience = 1
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\TabletMode = 1`

Comment: I have added it, this only helps to show the touch keyboard, doesnt improve the toggle experience

Comment: Yes, this is by design. The configuration I mentioned above works on the system, not browser-specific. If you want this touch keyboard to be like a mobile device, I think you need to look for some related extensions to achieve this requirement.